# Can I have a member variable that is only created with a factory method?

Tags: c++

I've got a class with a private constructor and a factory method.

Is it possible to have an instance of that class be a member variable of another class?  If I try to just do it normally, it won't compile because it cannot call the constructor.  Is it possible to get a member variable initialized with a factory method?

And if not, what are my options?  Do I need to use some kind of pointer?

```
class ClassWithPrivateConstructor
{
private:
   ClassWithPrivateConstructor(){}
public:
  static ClassWithPrivateConstructor Create(); // factory method
};

class ClassWithMemberVariable
{
  ClassWithPrivateConstructor a;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course. Since the member can't be default-initialised, you'll need an initialiser:

```
ClassWithPrivateConstructor a = ClassWithPrivateConstructor::Create();
```

or, if you're stuck with a pre-2011 variant of the language, an initialiser in each constructor:

```
public:
    ClassWithMemberVariable() : a(ClassWithPrivateConstructor::Create()) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just ensure that each constructor initialises the member via the factory method:

```
class ClassWithMemberVariable
{
  ClassWithPrivateConstructor a;
  ClassWithMemberVariable(): a(ClassWithPrivateConstructor::Create()) {
    ;
  }
};
```